# select from another mysql host

Tags: mysql, select, federated

is it possible to execute a SELECT command on a mysql host db2, being logined to mysql host db1?

e.g. i'm logined on mysql server db1, and i want to SELECT some data from db1 tables and db2 server tables with one query. i've found out that i can use [FEDERATED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html) tables, but i'm looking for a simpler way, if it exists

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a simpler way. I can't find one, at least.
I did a bit or research on this. (Was interested.) The manual entry for the SELECT query mentions nothing that would allow it to connect to a database on a second server, and I can't see anything else that would allow it either. *(Nothing in the JOINS, nothing in the CREATE TABLE syntax, just nothing...)*

Except for the FEDERATED engine, that is. This is exactly why it was crated; to allow this sort of thing.

I suppose you could try to set your OS up to create a symbolic link to the data files of a second server and have the first server set up a table that targets that, but that's hardly an improvement over the FEDERATED engine.

In any case, if there are other alternatives, I doubt they are *simpler* than the FEDERATED engine. I would at least give it a try.